# Grabbing color palette from YouTube thumbnail

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-api, color-palette

I'm trying to grab the color palette from YouTube thumbnails, to better blend the YouTube video with a whole website design, and I'm wondering if there is any way of doing this?

I've tried using color-thief (https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief) and this code (with no luck):

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
  var colorThief = new ColorThief();
  colorThief.getColor(img);
};
img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
img.src = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/NuEfvIca0XU/mqdefault.jpg
```

From this I'm just getting this error:

```
Image from origin 'http://img.youtube.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access
```

Any way of bypassing this, or grabbing the color palette without downloading the thumbnail off of YouTube and saving it on my server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution, but it involves passing the imagelink through http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

This leaves us with:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
  var colorThief = new ColorThief();
  colorThief.getColor(img);
};
img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
img.src = 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+id+'/mqdefault.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

The best idea is to implement this on the server side, because the most of browsers automatically disable fetching something through javascript from another domain names due to security reasons. That's why you get a [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: So, have the nodeserver grab the color palette for each YouTube video you mean? Or download the thumbnail on the server for each thumbnail?

Comment: I'm not a `nodejs` specialist, but I'll prefer this way: 1. download the image from youtube. 2. define color palette 3. store it to the database 4. remove image

Comment: I'd like to avoid this, since the website is based on channels filled with YouTube videos, and it would be extra load on it to download an image on each song change or song skipped for each channel.

Comment: @KasperRT let's wait for another solutions! I'm interested in your question too