# Redrawing youtube thumbnails in canvas and storing them in localStorage

Tags: javascript, canvas, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I've to get thumbnails from their url and redraw them in canvas, additionally I need to store them in localStorage -so that after closing and re-opening the window they wouldn't get lost.

```
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
window.localStorage.canvas = [];
img.onload = function() {
    c.width = img.width
    c.height = img.height
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    var data = c.toDataURL();
    image.src = data;
    document.body.appendChild(image)
    window.localStorage.canvas.push(data)
};
img.src = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/vYOangK3kAw/0.jpg';
```

Using the code above I'm getting the code below:

`Image from origin 'https://img.youtube.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

When i remove `crossOrigin` attribute from image `img` which is used as buffer for redrawing. Error is changed to:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass the request through a proxy server that will set cors sharing, here is a similar (almost exact) case as your question:

[Grabbing color palette from YouTube thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731209/grabbing-color-palette-from-youtube-thumbnail)

I believe it is the only way.